I can't get an array in the for loop in Shopify
I'm using metaobjects in collections, in which I specify values.
This is how I can get the values as an array:
{{ collection.metafields.custom.filters.value.options }}

and I get this:
["option1","option2","option3"]

But when I try to get it in the for loop, I get nothing. I'm doing this:
{% for item in collection.metafields.custom.filters.value.options %}
   {{ item }}
{% endfor %}

I can't understand why this doesn't output anything as I use an array to get in a loop.
What is the problem here?

I was almost close to the right solution.
I just need to add a second property value at the end of the metafield call.
Like that:
collection.metafields.custom.filters.value.options.value

With the for loop it looks like this:
{% for item in collection.metafields.custom.filters.value.options.value %}
   {{ item }}
{% endfor %}

